# Enviar una señal de cambio de una variable

Tags: python, python-3.7, pyqt5

Tengo un codigo en python de control de acceso de entrada a un parque de niños, donde ingreso a un listView un nombre, nombre de representante, hora de entrada, hora de salida y un cronometro que actualiza el tiempo o segundo a segundo hasta llegar a cero.

El problema que tengo es que cuando lo quiero modificar, es decir agregarle mas tiempo, la hora de salida no se me actualiza, ya que es un Set que esta en una funciona llamada actualizar cronometro, lo que quiero saber es como puedo avisarle a esa funcion que ese valor a sido cambiado. cabe destacar que el archivo que actualiza el cronometro no es el mismo que lo modifica. Aqui comparto un poco del codigo

Archivo agregar.py

```
class CronometroItem(QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, nombre, representante, hora_entrada, hora_salida):
        super().__init__(f"{nombre} - {representante} - {hora_entrada} - {hora_salida}")
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.representante = representante
        self.hora_entrada = hora_entrada
        self.hora_salida = hora_salida
        self.tiempo_restante = QTime(0, 0, 0)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.actualizar_cronometro)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.actualizar_cronometro()
        
    
    def actualizar_cronometro(self):
            self.tiempo_restante = self.tiempo_restante.addSecs(-1)
            if self.tiempo_restante == QTime(0, 0, 0):
                    self.timer.stop()
                    self.setText(f"{self.nombre} - {self.representante} - {self.hora_entrada} - {self.hora_salida} - 00:00:00")
                    self.setBackground(QColor("red"))
            else:
                    self.setText(f"{self.nombre} - {self.representante} - {self.hora_entrada} - {self.hora_salida} - {self.tiempo_restante.toString('HH:mm:ss')}")
                    if self.tiempo_restante > QTime(0, 10, 0):
                        self.setBackground(QColor("#8BC34A"))  # verde
                    elif self.tiempo_restante < QTime(0,10, 0):
                        self.setBackground(QColor("#FFEB3B"))  # amarillo
                    else:
                        self.setBackground(QColor("#F44336"))
```

Archivo modificar

```
def modificar_elemento(self):
        tiempo_adicional = int(self.tiempo_label.text())
        nueva_hora_salida = self.hora_salida_mod
        tiempo_delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=tiempo_adicional)
        nueva_hora_salida = (datetime.datetime.strptime(nueva_hora_salida, '%I:%M %p') + 
                             tiempo_delta).strftime('%I:%M %p')
        
        self.nueva_hora_salida = nueva_hora_salida

        tiempo_inicial = datetime.datetime.strptime(nueva_hora_salida, '%I:%M %p') - datetime.datetime.strptime(self.hora_entrada_mod, '%I:%M %p')
        # Actualizar la base de datos
        tiempo_inicial = str(tiempo_inicial)

        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('mundoKids.db')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            
            cursor.execute("UPDATE clientes SET hora_salida=?, tiempo=? WHERE nombre=? AND representante=?", 
                        (nueva_hora_salida, tiempo_inicial, self.nombre_mod, self.representante_mod))
            
            conn.commit()
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
       

        # Actualizar el elemento de la lista 
        self.selected_item.setText(f"{self.nombre_mod} - {self.representante_mod} - {self.hora_entrada_mod} - {self.nueva_hora_salida} - {self.tiempo_restante}")
        self.selected_item.tiempo_restante = self.tiempo_restante.addSecs(tiempo_adicional*60)
        self.close()
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, ya que no logro dar con la respuesta y llevo dias